# SharePoint 2007: Content Query Web Part - How to update the "WebURL" property to point at a list that's relative to the site the web part is on?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I'm attempting to point a CQWP at a list (in SP2007) that exists per site that's created. In the ".webpart" file, I've modified the "WebURL" to the following:

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~site</property>
```

However, this throws up the following error:

"~site" contains illegal character '~'.

Each site is going to have a certain list available and I want the CQWP to point that the list relative to that site. Any ideas on how to resolve the above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks